# Cant upgrade apple developer account to business account

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I have created and uploaded an app to App Store. My app is designed specifically for the employees of an organisation. That is public user can't use the app. So app was rejected. Apple tells us to distribute the app as custom business app. I have developer account(it is organisation account not individual account). How can I upgrade the account to business type. I can’t login into business.apple.com using my Apple ID associated with my developer account. How Can I upgrade to business account. My organisation has a DUNS number.

Comment: Why are you asking a question about your business with Apple, Inc. here?  You should contact Apple, Inc.  I don't even know what is the thing that you call a 'business account.'  Are you referring to an enterprise account?

Comment: Voting to close as this is a Apple customer service question, not one about writing code.

Comment: You need to create an enterprise account if you want to distribute internal apps for your company, bypassing the App Store. Create a new account here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/ There's no way to upgrade an existing account, although I suppose you could just cancel your old one if you don't need it. It's not unusual for companies to have both a regular paid account and an enterprise developer account.

Comment: Now that Xcode Cloud and the store API's exist, I don't think stackoverflow can reject these types of questions, they are (and IMHO always have been) build questions, even if Apple's lack of detail spurs many unnecessary queries.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct solution I can think of is to re-submit the app, so that it forces an approval conversation, and when they tell you to use the alternative distribution, tell them to tell you what to do next.

I don't think I have seen any aspect of this on the websites, only from watching this WWDC video:

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10667

Answer (score -1):

You can register your organisation just here https://register.apple.com